# Prove that $1 \leq A \leq \frac{5}{4}$ and $0 \leq B < \frac{81}{16}$

Tags: polynomials, roots, symmetric-polynomials, quartics

It’s known that A and B are real numbers it is also known that the polynomial P(x) has 4 real roots

$$P (x) = x^4 − 3x^3 + 3x^2 − Ax + B$$
I did come up with a solution for A and I was hoping to apply it to B but I just couldn’t.

If a polynomial has 4 roots it has 3 extremums. These extremums have different signs. That means that the derivative has 3 roots.

$$p’(x) = 4x^3-9x^2+6x-A$$

If a derivative has 3 roots it has 2 extremums (different signs). The second derivative has 2 roots.

$$p’’(x) = 12x^2-18x+6$$
The roots are 1 and $\frac{1}{2}$.

$$p’(1) = 1 -A$$
$$p’(1/2) = 5/4 - A$$
These extremums have to have different signs.

$$(1-A)(5/4-A)\leq 0$$
To apply the same for B I have to find the roots of the derivative.

I also came up with a solution for one part of B but really don’t like it (the limitation is stronger than required and it is kinda sloppy).

$$B = {x_1}{x_2}{x_3}{x_4} $$
$$3={x_1}+{x_2}+{x_3}+{x_4}$$
$$3 = {x_1}{x_2}+…+{x_3}{x_4}$$

$$9= {x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2+{x_4}^2+2( {x_1}{x_2}+…+{x_3}{x_4})$$
$$3= {x_1}^2+{x_2}^2+{x_3}^2+{x_4}^2$$
Suppose ${y_i} = abs({x_i})$
$$3 = {y_1}^2+{y_2}^2+{y_3}^2+{y_4}^2 $$
$$sqrt[2] {\frac{{y_1}^2+{y_2}^2+{y_3}^2+{y_4}^2}{4}} \geq \sqrt[4] {{y_1}{y_2}{y_3}{y_4}}$$
$$ \frac{81}{16} \geq \frac{9}{16} \geq {y_1}{y_2}{y_3}{y_4} \geq {x_1}{x_2}{x_3}{x_4}$$

Comment: Feel free to change the title I’m not that good at Latex

Comment: Here's a guess: try Lagrange multipliers on the roots to maximize/minimize $A$ and $B$ subject to symmetric polynomial conditions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to get estimations for $B$.

Let $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are roots.

Thus, $$3=ab+ac+bc+ad+bd+cd\leq\frac{(a+b+c)^2}{3}+d(3-d)=\frac{(3-d)^2}{3}+d(3-d),$$
which gives $$2d^2-3d\leq0$$ or
$$0\leq d\leq\frac{3}{2},$$ which gives $$0\leq abcd\leq\frac{81}{16}$$ and $$0\leq B\leq\frac{81}{16}.$$
The right equality does not occur because if $a=b=c=d=\frac{3}{2}$, so $a+b+c+d=6,$ which is a contradiction,

which says $B<\frac{81}{16}.$

Comment: In my task it says that B <81/16 not equal, do you think you could explain that? :)

Comment: @Foorgy Infifcio Because if $a=b=c=d=\frac{3}{2}$, so $a+b+c+d=6,$ which is a contradiction, which says $B<\frac{81}{16}.$

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: Hey, just one more question, I can’t understand why $1 \leq A \leq \frac{5}{4}$ and not $1 < A < \frac{5}{4}$

Comment: @Foorgy Infifcio  $A=\frac{5}{4}$ occurs for $a=b=c=\frac{1}{2}$ and $d=\frac{3}{2},$ which says that $\frac{5}{4}$ is a maximal value of $A$.

Comment: Hey, Michael! What is the roots are all different?

Comment: @Foorgy Infifcio Yes, of course. Otherwise, it's impossible that the coefficient before $x^3$ would be equal to $-3$ and the coefficient before $x^2$ would be equal to $3$.

Comment: Well in your example a=b=c=1/2 these roots are equal aren’t they?

Comment: @Foorgy Infifcio Now, I understood your question. I thought you asked "What is the roots are all equal?"

Comment: If, I ment if not is. I’ve read my task once again and it says there that the roots are all different. Does that mean that $1<A<\frac{5}{4}$ (not less or equal)?

Comment: If $P(x)=x^4-3x^3+3x^2-1.1x+0.1$ so $P$ has four different roots.

Comment: so what? I think that A could not be = 1. Am I right?

Answer (score 4):

Let $a,b,c,d$ be the roots of $P$.

First we show the bound of $A$.
By Rolle's theorem, we know that $P'(x)=4x^3-9x^2+6x-A$ has at least $3$ roots.

At the same time, $P''(x)=12x^2-18x+6=6(x-1)(2x-1)$

We can easily see that $P'(x)$ is increasing in $]- \infty,\frac1 2]$ decreasing in $[\frac1 2,1]$ and increasing in $[1, +\infty[$.

However, these variations imply that $P'$ has a root in $]- \infty,\frac1 2]$, we call it $\alpha$ (because $\lim_{x \to -\infty} P'(x)=-\infty$,$\lim_{x \to +\infty} P'(x)=+\infty$ and $P'$ must cross at least $3$ times the $x$-axis)

Then $P'(\frac1 2)\geqslant P'(\alpha)=0 \implies \frac 5 4-A \geqslant 0$, hence $A \leqslant \frac 5 4$ as $P'$ increasing here.

Secondly, we prove the other bound in a different way,using Vieta's formula as $B$ can easily be expressed this way.

We have $a+b+c+d=3$ and $ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd=3$ and $B=abcd$.

The bound we want to show is $\left(\frac 3 2 \right)^4$, so if we can show that all roots are positive roots less than $\frac 3 2$, this will conclude.

Thus we now see that $(a+b+c+d)^2-2(ab+ac+ad+bc+bd+cd)=a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=3$

To deal with this sum, we use Cauchy-Schwarz inequality to bound the roots:

$3-a^2=b^2+c^2+d^2 \ge \frac{(b+c+d)^2}3=\frac{(3-a)^2}3$.

But, if $f(x)=3-x^2-\frac{(3-x)^2}3$ is a quadratic function with is positive if $x\in [0,\frac 3 2]$
This leads to the bound we wanted.

*(I didn't see your edit while writing...)*

Comment: Cool, you came up with an even better solution for B

Answer (score 4):

Denote the roots by $r_1,r_2,r_3,r_4$, and let $e_i$ denote the $i^{\text{th}}$ [elementary symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_symmetric_polynomial) on the roots. By [Vieta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), we have
$$e_1=3,\quad e_2=3,\quad e_3=A,\quad e_4=B.$$
We may then maximize and minimize $e_3$ subject to the above conditions on $e_1$ and $e_2$ using [Lagrange multipliers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier), for example, to find
$$1\leq A\leq \frac{5}{4}\quad \textrm{and}\quad 0\leq B\leq \frac{3}{16}.$$
(Note my upper bound for $B$ is significantly tighter than the one you propose.) The minimum values are obtained when
$$P(x)=x(x-1)^3=x^4-3x^3+3x^2-x,$$
and the maximum values when
$$P(x)=\left(x-\frac{3}{2}\right)\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^3=x^4-3x^3+3x^2-\frac{5}{4}x+\frac{3}{16}.$$

Comment: Unfortunately I wasn’t familiar with Lagrange multipliers. I tried reading about it and now I kinda understand. But still much to complicated for me. But thanks anyway

Comment: @FoorgyInfifcio No worries! You'll likely learn about them when you take your second calculus class, they are a very useful optimization method. In the meantime, Michael Rozenberg's answer looks good too.